# lambda function with multiple variables in sorting

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

There is a class with two domains of value. I want sort a list of such pairs with following criteria:

1. If the first domain are different, sort by first domain;
2. Otherwise, sort by second domain.

It is easy to sort only by first domain with lambda:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x:x.first)
```

or

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x:x.first)
```

But if I want to further compare x.second, how can I write lambda the function?

Comment: How many different versions of python are you using?

Comment: what are the type of values in `first` and `second`?

Answer (score 5):

Map them to `tuple`s!

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x:(x.first, x.second))
```

Tuple comparison happens in the same way you want -- Compare the first element of both tuples, if they are same, move on and decide outcome based on comparison of second element.

PS1: I am assuming `x.first` and `x.second` can be compared. (either types such as integers/string, or objects with `__eq__` defined.

PS2: I'd suggest implementing `__lt__(..)` on the `x`'s class. That way you wont have to pass in a `lambda` for the call to sort.